Minimizing sum(abs(Ax-c)) for binary decision variables - terminology and methods?
My problem requires choosing a fixed number of vectors from a large set of vectors such that the sum of these vectors is close to some known target vector. That is, given known parameters:
$$
l, m, n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
$$
\{a_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}: i \in 1..m, j \in 1..l\}
$$
$$
\{c_i \in \mathbb{R}: i \in 1..m\}
$$
minimize
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \left| c_i - \sum_{j=1}^l a_{i,j} x_j \right|
$$
s.t.
$$\sum_{j=1}^l x_j = n$$
$$x_j \in \{0,1\} ~\forall j$$
The typical problem size has $l \approx 1000 - 10000, m \approx 100, n \approx 2m$, though I may eventually want to explore larger numbers.
If the distributional properties of $a_{i,j}$ and $c_i$ are relevant, for the purposes of this problem, let's suppose the following:

The vectors $[a_{1,j},a_{2,j},...,a_{m,j}]$ are i.i.d. realisations from some $m$-dimensional random distribution, with $-k < a_{i,j} < k~\forall i,j$ for some known $k$.
The vector $[c_1,c_2,...,c_m]$ has been calculated as the sum of some set of $n$ vectors drawn from that same $m$-dimensional random distribution.

Formulating this as a MILP and solving via HiGHS works pretty well for smaller problem sizes, up to approx. $l = 2000, m = 30, n = 100$, but past that it's not scaling very well.
When I run it on larger problems, almost all the improvement comes in the first few minutes of run-time, and the solution I get after four hours is only marginally better than the one I had at three minutes. I don't need the absolute minimum but I need something pretty small, and for larger problems the solutions I'm getting aren't good enough.
There is some leeway to modify the problem:
The length of $l$ is not fixed. I can in fact increase or decrease it if I want, changing the number of $a_{i,j}$ parameters accordingly. However, if $l$ is too small, then there will be no possible "good enough" solution, and making it too large seems to be counterproductive, making the solution slightly worse for the same run-time. In theory, increasing $l$ should never worsen the global optimum, but I suspect the increased problem size is making it harder to find that optimum - the MIP gap is calculated as very close to 100%.
I am not too particular about the exact form of the objective function. If it makes things easier I'm happy to replace it with anything that gives a sensible norm for the vector $[(c_1- \sum_{j=1}^l a_{1,j} x_j),(c_2- \sum_{j=1}^l a_{2,j} x_j),...,(c_m- \sum_{j=1}^l a_{m,j} x_j)]$.
Currently I'm using HiGHS as a solver because that's what I have at hand, but I'm open to other free options if they can be easily applied in Python. I might be able to get access to Gurobi but this would be a less convenient option.
I'm happy to do some experimentation here but the time I have available to work on this is limited, so I'm trying to identify the best options for exploration.
My questions:

Does this problem of minimizing sum(abs($Ax-c$)) for binary $x$ have a standard name? It seems very similar to a knapsack problem, and I guess it could be translated to a multidimensional knapsack problem where each element of $Ax-c$ represents two constraints, but I'm not sure if that's a helpful way to formulate it. Not having a good term for this problem is getting in the way of looking for established methods.

Am I likely to get better results by changing approaches (e.g. transforming the problem, or switching to a different MILP solver, or to a constraint solver)? Or is this just inherently difficult to scale?



Would you please, write the whole math formulation you have with all of its relevant indices?

@A.Omidi Done - happy to edit further if anything more is needed for clarity here.

This looks somewhat like regressor selection and often people relax the hard cardinality-constraint to a l1-norm based proxy objective-term. See EE364b, Stanford University | l1-norm Methods for Convex-Cardinality Problems.

How you linearize can make a difference. If you are using two inequality constraints for the absolute value, you might try an equality-based linearization instead: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4554240/683666

You say "for larger problems the solutions I'm getting aren't good enough". Does that mean the objective value achieved fails to meet some target, or does it mean the optimality gap (which is likely inflated) remains too large?

@prubin Both, but mostly the former. For this problem I would expect the true optimum to tend to zero as $l$ tends to infinity, so relative gap is almost always going to be ~100% unless the problem is small enough for near-exhaustive search. Since I posted, I have been experimenting with reducing $l$ - effectively, constraining some of the $x_j$ to zero - and even though this obviously can't improve the true optimum, I'm getting markedly better results for a fixed run-time, which tells me that the earlier solutions weren't close to optimal. 1/2

@prubin For instance, at $l=20000, m=100, n=150$, running for 4 hours gets me an objective function equal to 224 units; at $l=10000$, running for only 2 hours gets me a slightly better solution (205 units); and at $l=2000$, running for only 1 hour gets me down to 126 units. Starting to look as throwing away choices is the way to get to a better solution; I guess that would come down to what's going on in the solver algorithm. 2/2

@RobPratt Thanks, I've used that approach in other problems before and had been wondering whether it was worth trying here - will give it a shot!

@sascha Thanks - I will have to think about that to see whether I can apply it here. In my case the requirement is not to minimise cardinality of $x$ or satisfy a less-than-or-equal-to condition, but to have it exactly equal to $n$ so I'm not sure how easily it will translate. In the cases I'm currently exploring, I suspect the cardinality constraint is somewhat redundant, in that any solution which doesn't have cardinality = $n$ will do badly on the objective function, but this may not be valid for all cases of interest.

If you replace the cardinality constraint with $\sum_i x_i + u - v = n$ where $u$ and $v$ are nonnegative variables, and add $\lambda \cdot (u + v)$ to the objective ($\lambda$ a positive penalty parameter), does the solver get to a near-optimal solution (for the modified problem) quickly? I'm wondering if Lagrangian relaxation would help.

@G_B, As an attempt, do you try choosing the $n$ elements of $x_{j}$ for which their associated $a_{i,j}$ being minimized? (E.g. by fixing the value of $x_{j}$ equal to one, for $n$ elements based on their minimum value of $a_{i,j}$ and comparing the result with the one you have)

In terms of l1-reg approaches, maybe there is some merrit in using 1d-optimization / root-finding meta-search (multiple invocations): opt-var is regularization-strength, root/objective is deviation from n. Maybe you hit your n, maybe you only hit n+-epsilon. | Maybe you even have a simple repair-approach to take an n+-epsilon solution and turn it into a starting-solution with n to bootstrap your exact approaches.

@A.Omidi I'm not sure I've understood correctly - you are suggesting choosing the $n$ values of $j$ that give the smallest values for $\sum_i a_{i,j}$? If so, I would expect that to result in large values for the $c_i-\sum_ja_{i,j}x_j$ terms, hence a very poor objective-function value.

@G_B, this is just a simple approach to take a primal bound. If the difference between $c_{i}$ and the summation of $a_{i,j}$ is too far, you are right and the result would be a worse case. But if you can somehow estimate this distance prior and fix the variable values based on it, I guess the result would be a good primal bound.

I do not know of a name for this problem, and I do not think switching to constraint programming will help.
If you are content with a heuristic approach (not requiring a provably optimal solution), you might look into what options your solver provides to emphasize improvement of the best incumbent over improvement of the best bound. My impression (based on your question and limited experimentation of my own) is that the lower bound is going to be a stubborn beast. In a trial with CPLEX ($l=20000, m=100, n=150$ with vectors drawn from the standard normal distribution) I got what I thought was pretty good improvement in the objective with a two minute time limit using a "MIP emphasis" parameter setting of 5 (which for CPLEX means "go all in on heuristics and forget the bound").
